# copy a record with amount x to x instances in another table with amount = 1

Tags: sql, copy, firebird

My SQL skills are quite sufficient for most of what I need, but this is beyond my knowledge. I have tried to write a procedure in Object Pascal generating SQL that works but it is rather slow.

I have a table containing records with amounts = or > 1.
Now I want to copy these records into another table "amount" times, so that 
the record that has an amount of 1 is copied once with an amount of 1 
and a record with the amount of 5 is copied 5 times, each with a new amount of 1.

Is it possible to do this in SQL?

Comment: You can try with recursive query.

Comment: Read documentation: the whole chapter **Procedural SQL** and then section about `EXECUTE BLOCK` at https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming two tables `source` and `target`:

```
create table source (
  id integer generated by default as identity constraint pk_source primary key,
  item_type integer not null,
  amount integer not null
);

create table target (
  id integer generated by default as identity constraint pk_target primary key,
  item_type integer not null,
  amount integer not null
);
```

Where `source` is populated as:

```
insert into source (item_type, amount) values (1, 5);
insert into source (item_type, amount) values (2, 1);
insert into source (item_type, amount) values (3, 2);
```

You can then copy these records into `target` with an anonymous procedure ([`execute block`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-execblock)):

```
execute block
as
declare item_type type of column source.item_type;
declare amount type of column source.amount;
begin
  for select item_type, amount from source into item_type, amount do
  begin
      while (amount > 0) do
      begin
        insert into target (item_type, amount) values (:item_type, 1);
        amount = amount - 1;
      end
  end
end
```

This copies the record from `source` into `target` (`amount`) times.

See also this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=95d48090cb5c4ad40ad26e77091ce6e1).

Comment: That's ok. Works for me. Thank you!